# Integrity constraint violation when using a Foreign key for a user role

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to define a role for my users using a "role_id" foreign key which referes to the "id" of my "roles" table.

The migrations worked well but when I'm trying to register I get an error.

Migration users

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->char('nni', 6);
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(1);
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
    }
```

Models/User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nni', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'role_id', 'admin', 'password',
    ];

[...]

public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Migration roles

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

[...]

}
```

The error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update >a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectsms`.`users`, >CONSTRAINT `users_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES >`roles` (`id`))

If you know where is my problem let me know !

Comment: note the migration order.  if the `users` table is being created before the `roles` table, it will fail the constraint when it tries to create.  foreign tables should be created first before trying to reference them.

Comment: The value of the `role_id` doesnt reference an entry in your `roles` table. Is there a role id = 1 in your `roles` table ? `$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(1);`

Comment: Tried, and got this : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`))`

Comment: @N69S I have no role_id = 1 in my roles table, why would I have it?

Comment: @Petoux because you set the default value of `role_id` in the table `users` to 1. If you have users without roles, set the field as nullable `$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->nullable();`

Comment: @N69S I want the default role to be 1, and all users with a role, how can I do that ? EDIT : Worked, I found my error, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your structure depends on the fact that every use must have a role, you should include the insertion of the default role in your migration.

```php
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table('roles')->insert([
            'id' => 1, //must be 1
            'name' => 'default',
            'description' => 'default role (just registered)',
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        ]);
    }

[...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, by default, every foreign key HAS to point to an existent primary key.
You have three alternatives.

- 1 Set the default value for role_id an existing id.
- 2 Delete all registers from **roles** table before migrate.
- 3 Set role_id as nullable()